# InvokeMember object[] parameters

Tags: c#, object

#### The problem

This may be a very simple question, but it's had me stuck for some time:
InvokeMember can accept an object[] representing the parameters needed to pass to the method.  I have two objects (list of obj, string foo).  I can pass either variable successfully to the method, but when I try and pass both I get a Method 'x' NotFound exception.

#### Details

Calling the method:

```
classtype.InvokeMember(someMethodName, 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod|BindingFlags.Static,
            null,
            null,
            new object[]{ someListOfObjects, stringValue});
```

The receiving Method:

```
public static string TestMethod(object foo)
{
    return "foo";
}
```

Notes:
When passing `new object[]{someListOfObjects}` or `new object[]{stringValue}` I reach the destination method as expected, however when I try and pass both it fails to find the method.  Is my incoming parameter on TestMethod correct?

When I change TestMethod to accept an object[], the method is never found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're passing in an array with two elements, so it views that as the argument array, looking for a method with two parameters. You want to end up with an array of length 1, whose sole element is an object which also happens to be an array (of length 2).

Options:

- Cast it to `object` so that it the compiler parameter array to build a wrapping array

  ```
  (object) new object[] { someListOfObjects, stringValue }
  ```
- Create the array directly yourself:

  ```
  new object[] { new object[] { someListOfObjects, stringValue } }
  ```
- Modify the `TestMethod` parameters to match the array:

  ```
  public static string TestMethod(List<object> foo, string bar)
  ```

Comment: At this point I'm basically combining those two parameters, how can I unbox or interact with these values in the invoked method?

Comment: @Aardvark: Cast it to `object[]` and then fetch each value separately... or change your method signature to have two parameters. (It's not really clear what you're trying to do.)

Comment: That may be an indicator that I'm doing something wrong.  I attempted to keep my question generic so it could help others but it may be time for some more information.  I'm calling generic methods that will either validate data entered by the user or enter data based on calculations that occur in the invoked method.  The string value represents the value entered by the user, the list represents data column definitions (which may or may not be edited in the invoked methods).  Is it possible to use InvokeMethod() to call a method with 2 parameters rather than combine them into one object?

Comment: @Aardvark: Yes - you just need to declare the two parameters. If you'd done that to start with, your existing code would have been absolutely fine :) I'll edit to mention that.

Comment: Holy epiphany, thanks so much for your help.  That'll make my life a lot easier!